# how to make an alert message pop up when a radio button is unselected in asp.net vb code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to vb and asp.net coding and want an error message to pop up if a radio button is unselected, how could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to show how you would do this for individual radios and for a RadioButtonList below. Basically, you need to set an event handler for all radios in the group you want to check for when a radio is changed. That event handler should check to see if the radio you are interested in is still checked, and if not do the alert.

For checking individual RadioButtons you need to check for input.name = GroupName property.

For checking RadioButtonGroup items you need to check for input.name = the Id of the server control. The html Id of the individual items is always the Id of the server control + _ + the index of the ListItem (0 / zero indexed)

EXAMPLE:

ASPX page code

```
<span>INDIVIDUAL RADIO BUTTONS</span><br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="buttons" Text="Item 1" Checked="true"  />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="buttons" Text="Item 2" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioButton3" runat="server" GroupName="buttons" Text="Item 3" />
<br /><br />
<span>RADIO BUTTON LIST</span><br />
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rb_Radios" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

VB.NET Code

```
 Private Sub _Default_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType, "radioChangeAlert", "
            document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) => {
                // For handling individual radio buttons
                if(input.type==='radio' && input.name==='buttons'){ 
                    input.onchange=function(){
                        if(!document.getElementById('" & radioButton1.ClientID & "').checked){alert('Item 1 no longer checked!');};
                    }
                };
                // For handling a RadioButtonList
                if(input.type==='radio' && input.name==='rb_Radios'){ 
                    input.onchange=function(){
                        if(!document.getElementById('rb_Radios_" & rb_Radios.Items.IndexOf(rb_Radios.Items.FindByText("Item 2")) & "').checked){alert('Item 2 no longer checked!');};
                    }
                };
            });
            ", True)
    End Sub
```

Of course, if you want to just check at the point where the form is submitted then your code could be simpler.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Page.GetType, "checkRadios", "
    // individual radios
    if(!document.getElementById('" & radioButton1.ClientID & "').checked){alert('Item 1 must be checked!');return false;};
    // RadioButtonList item
    if(!document.getElementById('rb_Radios_" & rb_Radios.Items.IndexOf(rb_Radios.Items.FindByText("Item 2")) & "').checked){alert('Item 2 must be checked!');return false;};
")
```